# Blazor - Merge .json file to IConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor

So in Blazor you get an instance implementing IConfiguration as default service. No need to register it yourself. My Question is: Can I load additional .json files into the default IConfiguration instance?
And if not, is it possible to register my own IConfiguration and load different .json files into it? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some useful documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

Yes, you can load additional files like this:

(assuming that var stream is a stream from a Json configuration file).

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(stream);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can this be called after `builder.Build().RunAsync()` or does it have to happen before?

Comment: `builder.Build().RunAsync()` this should  call after all the service you want to build. Anything after `builder.Build()` execution will not be build and it will through `Cannot modify ServiceCollection after application is built.'
` Exception. Hope you got the point.